# How to use Sigma grid built-in capabilities to calculate aggregates where Sortable property set to TRUE

Tags: sigma-grid-control

How to use Sigma grid built-in capabilities to calculate aggregates where Sortable property set to TRUE, So that We can also sort the columns but It must not affect Aggregate Row(Or Totals row, That row should not be sorted as it provides the Total of all the cols and if sorted ,totals row will come up and may cause mess in the grid). Sorting must be done for all the rows on clicking that column header but not for the last row which has aggregate of all the rows. Please take the following example,click on link below:

http://www.sigmawidgets.com/products/sigma_grid/demos/example_aggregate.html

but here Sortable property has been set to false. I need to implement it in JSP 
Thanks and Regards 
Gurpreet Singh

Comment: The link you've provided appears to be broken.

Comment: I have editted the link ..please check now..
Thanks